# Reference filters from different svg file

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

How do you reference filters which are defined in a different file? For instance there is a `filter.svg` in the folder `assets` which has:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#39F" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F3F" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Now in another file I draw some shapes in another `svg` element. How do I apply this gradient filter? Simply: `fill="url(assets/filter.svg#gradient)"`? Because it looks like it is not picking up the definition.

Comment: This is in chrome, right? Please be more specfic about where you see the issue in the future :) It should work just fine in Opera (Presto) and Firefox, see e.g http://dahlström.net/svg/usingExternalGradient.svg.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Thank you so much for your example. I didn't know about xlink yet. Unfortunately this only works in my Firefox (as you stated). Not in Chrome 31, bummer :(

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, Chrome (still!) does not support referencing filters, fills, strokes, clip-paths, masks or markers defined in external files,  as at Chrome v45.

See [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212) which seems to be tracking this issue.

There also seem to be [webkit bugs](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105904) on this, so although I have not tested it myself, I would assume that other webkit based browsers may also have this limitation.