# CSS reference to SVG filter in separate element

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

Playing around with SVG filters, I ran into an issue with referencing an SVG filter from CSS. In some situations, applying a filter will remove the element to which the filter is applied from the page. I thought that there could be 2 causes:

1. the fact that I was adding the filters dynamically using [D3JS](https://d3js.org/);
2. the fact that I am referencing the filters in CSS, defined in a separate file.

To test this, I created a [**MWE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fkbtn8s9/1/) that demonstrates the issue. For me, this renders in Firefox and Chrome with nothing in the left box and a gray circle (the expected result) in the right box. This eliminates cause 1, I think. After I did this, I tried:

1. Referencing using `url(.#filter-id)`, so with a leading dot. This did not change the result.
2. Moving the `defs` in the same `svg` element as where the circle is. This [**fixes**](https://jsfiddle.net/fkbtn8s9/2/) the issue.

**My question:** is it still possible to somehow reference a filter that is defined in a separate SVG element? I would very much prefer to do it that way in my application. I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461308/reference-filters-from-different-svg-file) that there are problems with external files, but a different element in the same file should surely be possible?

Comment: Are you trying to write #filter-id in a CSS file. There's no element with an Id of filter-id in that file because it's in the HTML file.

Comment: Well, yes, that is why I tried `url(.#filter-id)`, I read that that should make it look in the HTML file. It did not, for me at least.

Comment: You should find some better reading material then: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-urls **For CSS style sheets, the base URL is that of the style sheet itself, not that of the styled source document.**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just double checked, but on JSFiddle, everything is inlined anyway, so then the `.` reference should work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `display:none` in the `hidden` class, you can use another way to hidden, this for example:

```
svg.hidden {
  height:0;
  margin:0;
  border:none;
}
```

```js
var svg = d3.select('#container').append('svg'),
    defs = svg.append('defs'),
    dsFilter;

svg.attr('width', 400).attr('height', 200);

dsFilter = defs.append('filter').attr('id', 'grayscale-d3')
dsFilter.append('feColorMatrix')
  .attr('type', 'matrix')
  .attr('values',
        '0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 ' +
        '0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 ' +
        '0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 ' +
        '0      0      0      1 0')

svg.append('text').attr('x', 2).attr('y', 2).text('appended by D3');
svg.append('circle').attr('class', 'd3').attr('cx', 200).attr('cy', 120).attr('r', 60);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

circle {
  fill: #bada55;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
circle.of {
  filter: url('#grayscale-of');
}
circle.d3 {
  filter: url('#grayscale-d3');
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
svg.hidden {
  height:0;
  margin:0;  
  border:none;
}

text {
  dominant-baseline: text-before-edge;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="hidden">
  <defs>
    <filter id="grayscale-of">
      <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                             0      0      0      1 0"
                     type="matrix">
      </feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="container">
  <svg width="400" height="200">
    <text x="2" y="2">already in page</text>
    <circle class="of" cx="200" cy="120" r="60" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It had to be something simple like that! Thank you so much, I don't think I would have figured this out... [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkbtn8s9/3/), if people look for it.